# database----database normalization

Tags: database, database-design

someone told me the following table isn't fit for the second database normalization. but i don't know why? i am a newbie of database design, i have read some tutorials of the 3NF. but to the 2NF and 3NF, i can't understand them well. expect someone can explain it for me. thank you,

```
    +------------+-----------+-------------------+
    pk                pk             row
  +------------+-----------+-------------------+
      A                  B                  C
   +------------+-----------+-------------------+
        A                  D                  C
 +------------+-----------+-------------------+
          A                  E                  C
  +------------+-----------+-------------------+
```

Comment: This is a pretty trivial table design - is this homework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

About your example: that table doesn't fit the second database normalization (with your sample data, I presume that the C depends only on A). The second normalization form requires that:

> ```
> No non-prime attribute in the table is functionally dependent on a
> ```
>
> proper subset of a candidate key
>   ([Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization#Non-first_normal_form_.28NF.C2.B2_or_N1NF.29))

So the C depends on "A", which is a subset of your primary key. Your primary key is a ***special superkey*. (dportas point out the fact that it can't be called candidate key, since it's not minimal).**

Let's say more about the second normalization form. Transform your example a little for easy understanding, presume that there's a table `CUSTOMER(customer_id, customer_name, address)`. A super key is a sub-set of your properties which uniquely determine a tube. In this case, there are 3 super key: (customer_id) ; (customer_id, customer_name) ; (customer_id, customer_name, address). (Customer name may be the same for 2 people)

In your case, you have determined (customer_id, customer_name) be the Primary Key. It violated the second form rules; since it only needs customer_id to determine uniquely a tube in your database. **For the sake of theory accuration, the problem here raised from the choice of primary key(it's not a candidate key), though the same argument can be applied to show the redundance. You may find some useful example [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Second_normal_form).**

The third normal form states that:

> Every non-prime attribute is
>   non-transitively dependent on every
>   candidate key in the table

Let give it an example. Changing the previous table to fit the second form, now we have the table `CUSTOMER(customer_id,customer_name, city, postal_code)`, with customer_id is primary key.

Clearly enough, "postal_code" depends on the "city" of customer. This is where it violated the third rule: postal_code depends on city, city depends on customer_id. That means postal_code transitively depends on customer_id, so that table doesn't fit the third normal form.

To correct it, we need to eliminate the transitive dependence. So we split the table into 2 table: `CUSTOMER(customer_id, customer_name, city)` and `CITY(city, postal_code)`. This prevent the redundance of having too many tubes with the same city & postal_code.

Comment: (customer_id) ; (customer_id, customer_name) ; (customer_id, customer_name, address) cannot all be candidate keys because they are subsets of each other. A Candidate Key must be minimal.

Comment: @dportas: actually, the database terms are not the same among books of different authors.

Comment: àng: I can't imagine any reputable source defining a candidate key as anything other than a minimal superkey - it would make nonsense of 2NF and 3NF.

Comment: @dportas: after googling, I admit that a candidate key should be a minimal superkey. So my example gives another aspect of that: when the primary key is wrong determined, it causes the same effect. I edited the answer to reflect that fact. Thanks for the correction.

Answer (score 1):

Your question cannot be answered properly unless you state what dependencies are supposed to be satisfied here. You appear to have two attributes with the same name (pk), in which case this table doesn't even satisfy 1NF because it doesn't qualify as a relation.